# “Friend” relationships (2 tables)

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables like this

```
Users table
id    | name
-------------
1     |  s1
2     |  s2
3     |  s3
4     |  s4
5     |  s5
6     |  s6



friends table
friendID | user_a | user_b
--------------------
1        |   1    |   2
2        |   3    |   1
3        |   4    |   2
4        |   1    |   3
```

I want to run this query: **Who is friends with s1?**
This is my current query, but it doesn't work

```
select a.name
from users a, friends b
where a.id=b.user_b
and b.user_a = (select b.user_a
               from friends
               where a.name='s1');
```

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to join Users table twice with each `user_a` and `user_b`:

Try this query:

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM Users u 
  JOIN friends f
    ON u.id = f.user_b
  JOIN Users u1
    ON u1.id = f.user_a
 WHERE u1.name = 's1';
```

Result:

```
╔══════╗
║ NAME ║
╠══════╣
║ s2   ║
║ s3   ║
╚══════╝
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83f96/4)

---

**Edit**: In your query (which you have tried) you used outer table's id and name in subquery. So you needed to use sub table's id and name like this:

```
select a.name
from users a, friends b
where a.id=b.user_b
and b.user_a IN (select id
                 from users
                 where name='s1');
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83f96/15)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name
FROM users a, friends b, users c
WHERE a.id=b.user_a
    AND b.user_b=c.id
    AND a.name='s1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT DISTINCT users.name 
FROM users, friends
WHERE (users.id=friends.user_a OR users.id=friends.user_b )
      AND (friends.user_a='1' OR friends.user_b='1')
      AND (users.id!='1')`                                                                              

Result:

s2
s3
```